# 4*4 Word Square

Tags: crosswords, word-square

A word square is a puzzle in which letters can be placed into the grid below so that words are formed both horizontally and vertically. In this puzzle, the same four words are formed in both directions.

[image: the 4*4 grid]

For example, the words *saw*, *ate*, and *wet* can be placed in a 3*3 grid as such:

```
S A W
A T E
W E T
```

In no particular order, the clues are as follows:

- Old fashioned form of Ctrl+V.
- Area of land surrounded by water.
- To require.
- An object conveying meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words are:

> NEED, GLUE, ISLE, SIGN
>  [image: Screenshot of the completed square.]

"*Old fashioned form of Ctrl+V."*

> Glue is a synonym of paste. Not sure how old fashioned fits it though. I simply searched "define paste" and looked for four letter synonyms.

"*Area of land surrounded by water.*"

> I initially thought *holm*, but *isle* is more common due to its similarity to *island*.

"*To require."*

> My thoughts immediately went to *need*, so I ran with it.

"*An object conveying meaning.*"

> This one took me a moment, and I initially thought *book*. However, after re-reading the specification that "*In this puzzle, the same four words are formed in both directions.*", *sign* was the only one that met this requirement.

Comment: Congratulation! : ) I called glue old-fashioned simply because it was how you pasted things before computers.

Answer (score 6):

> [image]
>  Old fashioned form of Ctrl-V (Paste) - GLUE
>  Area of land surrounded by water - ISLE
>  To require - NEED
>  An object conveying meaning - SIGN